# Is there any difference between $X\times^G Y$ and $X\times_G Y$?

Tags: geometry, notation, group-actions

Let $X,Y$ be "spaces" on which a group $G$ acts. Typically I see the notation $X\times_G Y$ to denote the quotient of $X\times Y$ by the relation $(x,y) = (gx,gy)$.

In a paper I now see the notation $X\times^G Y$, without explanation, though it is in the same context - $G$ acts on $X$ and $Y$.

Are both notations standard/common (for the quotient $(x,y) = (gx,gy)$)?

EDIT: The paper is [Hinich-Vaintrob Augmented Teichmuller spaces and orbifolds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.2859.pdf). Remark 3.1.3(i)

Comment: Can you name the paper so people can help you with that context?

Comment: Usually $X\times^G Y$ means $X\times Y$ modulo the relation $(x,y)\sim(xg^{-1},gy)$.

Comment: @MarkS. added a link!